# Custom Script for Multiple Execution of Docker-Compose

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I'm relative new to Bash and i'm trying to clean things up and have a better folder structure.

I'm currently trying to build a script that have options up and down like the famous command "`Docker-Compose Up`" & "`Docker-Compose Down`"

**My only issue is that i'm not too familiar with If function or if anyother function to make Up and Down as options or arguments**

## **My current scripts is below**

### compose-up.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose -f /home/home/compose/tools.yml -f /home/home/compose/dashboards.yml up -d
```

### compose-down.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose -f /home/home/compose/tools.yml -f /home/home/compose/dashboards.yml down
```

**The new script should be named compose.sh and i would like if i can just type**

`./compose.sh up` to run and create those containers in Docker

`./compose-sh down` to stop and delete those containers in Docker

### MAKING IT DYNAMIC = IDEAL SCRIPT

The biggest design flaw with my code is that its not dynamic. This is probably a more complicated code down the road for improvement but if its easier for someone to create a code to basically run `Docker-Compose Up` on all xml files within specific directory such as `/home/home/compose`. For example, all xml files within the folder "compose"  will be automatically docker-compose up and if i want to do docker-compose down too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SCRIPT

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to stop all compose-related containers for the YAML files in the current 
# folder.

# It uses the `docker-compose down` command to stop and remove the containers.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, stops and removes the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
down() {
    local yml_files=($(find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yml"))

    # Check if any YAML files are found in the current folder.
    if [ ${#yml_files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No yml files found in the current folder."
        exit 1
    fi

    local output=""
    for file in "${yml_files[@]}"; do
        output=$(sudo docker-compose -f "$file" down 2>&1)
        if [[ $output == *"No resource found to remove"* ]]; then
            echo "No compose files are running for $(basename "$file")."
        else
            echo "All compose-related containers are removed for $(basename "$file")."
        fi
    done
}

# Function to start all compose-related containers for the YAML files in the current 
# folder.

# It uses the `docker-compose up -d` command to start the containers in detached 
# mode.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, starts the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
up() {
    local yml_files=($(find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yml"))

    # Check if any YAML files are found in the current folder.
    if [ ${#yml_files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No yml files found in the current folder."
        exit 1
    fi

    for file in "${yml_files[@]}"; do
        sudo docker-compose -f "$file" up -d
        echo "All compose-related containers are started for $(basename "$file")."
    done
}

# Function to restart all compose-related containers for the YAML files in the 
# current folder.

# It uses the `docker-compose restart` command to restart the containers.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, restarts the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
restart() {
    local yml_files=($(find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yml"))

    # Check if any YAML files are found in the current folder.
    if [ ${#yml_files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No yml files found in the current folder."
        exit 1
    fi

    for file in "${yml_files[@]}"; do
        sudo docker-compose -f "$file" restart
        echo "All compose-related containers are restarted for $(basename "$file")."
    done
}

# Function to stop all compose-related containers for the YAML files in the current 
# folder.

# It uses the `docker-compose stop` command to stop the containers.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, stops the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
stop() {
    local yml_files=($(find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yml"))

    # Check if any YAML files are found in the current folder.
    if [ ${#yml_files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No yml files found in the current folder."
        exit 1
    fi

    for file in "${yml_files[@]}"; do
        sudo docker-compose -f "$file" stop
        echo "All compose-related containers are stopped for $(basename "$file")."
    done
}

# Function to pull and start all compose-related containers for the YAML files in 
# the current folder.

# It calls the `down` and `up` functions to achieve this.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, pulls and starts the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
pull() {
    down
    up
}

# Function to start all compose-related containers for the YAML files in the current 
# folder.

# It uses the `docker-compose start` command to start the containers.

# @return: Exits the script with an error message if no YAML files are found in the 
# current folder.

# Otherwise, starts the compose-related containers for each YAML file.
start() {
    local yml_files=($(find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yml"))

    # Check if any YAML files are found in the current folder.
    if [ ${#yml_files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No yml files found in the current folder."
        exit 1
    fi

    for file in "${yml_files[@]}"; do
        sudo docker-compose -f "$file" start
        echo "All compose-related containers are started for $(basename "$file")."
    done
}

# Main function to handle the user's choice of action.
# It calls the appropriate function based on the provided argument.

# @param $1: The action to perform (down, up, restart, stop, pull, start).
# @return: Exits the script with an error message if an invalid option is chosen.
# Otherwise, calls the corresponding function based on the provided argument.
main() {
    if [ "$1" == "down" ]; then
        down
    elif [ "$1" == "up" ]; then
        up
    elif [ "$1" == "restart" ]; then
        restart
    elif [ "$1" == "stop" ]; then
        stop
    elif [ "$1" == "pull" ]; then
        pull
    elif [ "$1" == "start" ]; then
        start
    else
     echo "Invalid option. Please choose one of the following: down, up, restart, \
stop, pull, start."
    fi
}

# Check if the script is being executed directly (not sourced).
# If so, call the main function with the provided arguments.
if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

I managed to create a bash code with the assistance of an old friend to make my code dynamic.
**Enjoy :)**

The script provides functions for common Docker Compose commands such as down, up, restart, stop, pull, and start.

**The main goal was to able to automate and run docker-compose files based on the current folder of pwd.**

The functions correctly find all YAML files in the current directory and use them as input for the Docker Compose commands.

## ADD TO PATH

```
1. sudo mv <CurrentPathofScript>/<ScriptName> /usr/local/bin/

2. sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/<ScriptName>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script, any additional command-line parameters are passed in numbered variables `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

You have a couple of invocations of `docker-compose` with similar options.  I'd wrap these in a *shell function*.  Here `"$@"` means "and all of the additional options passed to the function".

```bash
run_compose() {
  docker-compose -f /home/home/compose/tools.yml -f /home/home/compose/dashboards.yml "$@"
}
```

In the main script, there are a couple of ways to check what the argument is.  I might use the shell `case` statement here

```bash
case "$1" in
  up) run_compose up -d ;;
  down) run_compose down ;;
  *) echo 'usage: ./compose.sh [up|down]' >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

In the `case` statement, there are a series of lines starting with a shell glob and a close parenthesis.  If the expression `"$1"` matches the pattern, then the command is executed, up to the next `;;`.  `esac` ends the block.

Make sure to start the script with a "shebang" line, `#!/bin/sh` on a line on its own, and mark the script executable before you commit it to source control.